Sum of density functions
Consider four pdf $f_1(x), \ldots, f_4(x)$. For any $x$, $f_1(x) \neq \cdots \neq f_4(x)$.
Can we prove that $f_1(x) + f_2(x) \neq f_3(x) + f_4(x)$ for some $x$?

My first thought with this sort of thing is usually to consider if I can come up with a counterexample. Have you tried that? You'd be amazed how often it's a productive line to pursue.

An easy counterexample is the following: let the support of $x$ be $(0,1)$, and $f_k(x)=b_k\mathbb{I}(x\in [0,0.5])+(2-b_k)\mathbb{I}(x\in (0.5,1])$ be piecewise uniform PDFs with $b_k\in (0,2)$. Then if $b_1=3/2, b_2=1/2, b_3=1/4, b_4=7/4$, we have that $f_1(x)\neq f_2(x)\neq f_3(x)\neq f_4(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, but $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=f_3(x)+f_4(x)=2$  for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Upon dividing both sides by $2,$ you are asking whether it's possible to express one distribution in distinct ways as equal mixtures of two other distributions.  To appreciate how extremely flexible this is, see the plots at the beginning and end of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486951/919.

If by "for any $x$", you meant "for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$", I doubt if such $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$ existed at the first place, could you clarify?

@Zhanxiong Your doubt is likely predicated on the implicit assumption that the $f_i$ are continuous ;-).

@whuber Yes, that's why I urged the OP to make the domain of $f_i$s clear.

@Zhanxiong I don't understand, because continuity is a completely separate consideration from the domain.  Just to be clear: I referred explicitly to the functions $f_i$ as being continuous (in the sense of functions of one real variable), not to the distributions.

@whuber I am just wondering, for four continuous $f_i$s defined on the real line, can $f_i(x)$ be distinct for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$?  If yes, can you give me a concrete example?

@whuber Understood now. Another naive counterexample would be letting $f_3=1/3f_1+2/3f_2$, $f_4=2/3f_1+1/3f_2$. This construction is not related to the domain of $f$.

@whuber In fact, if we assume two pdfs $f_1$ and $f_2$ are everywhere continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and they don't intersect at any point. then it must hold $f_1(x) > f_2(x)$ or $f_2(x) > f_1(x)$ everywhere (otherwise intermediate value theorem will imply $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$ on some $x_0$), but this then yields $1 = \int_\mathbb{R} f_1(x) dx >< \int_\mathbb{R} f_2(x) dx = 1$, which is absurd.

@Zhanxiong - that was the point underlying whuber's comment beginning "Your doubt is likely predicated..."

That result does not follow from the assumptions, as I will show with a (constructive) counterexample.
Intuition
The idea is that since $f_1+f_2=f_3+f_4$ are sums of pdfs, we can start with that sum (which must be twice some pdf $f$) and try to split it into sums of functions that (i) are themselves pdfs and (ii) never agree at any argument $x.$  The validity of the conclusion comes down to whether this partitioning is ever possible.
The Intermediate Value Theorem of elementary Calculus tells us that if the $f_i$ are continuous, then the necessarily continuous differences $f_i-f_j$ must have zeros: that is, there will be at least one number $x$ at which they agree.  Thus, in any counterexample at least three of the $f_i$ must have discontinuities.  This leads us to contemplate where these discontinuities occur.  In the following construction, they will happen at the boundary of a region $\mathcal A.$

Analysis and Notation
Let $f$ be a probability density function (pdf) that is nonzero everywhere.  An example is the PDF of any Normal distribution.
Let $\mathcal A$ be any measurable set in the support of $f$ with probability $1/2.$  That is,
$$\frac{1}{2} = \int_{\mathcal A} f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Such sets always exist; for instance, you can take $\mathcal A = (-\infty, m]$ where $m$ is the median of $f.$
As is conventional, let $\mathcal I$ designate an indicator function, so that $\mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x) = 1$ when $x\in\mathcal A$ and otherwise $\mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x) = 0.$
I will construct counterexamples determined by a parameter $0\lt p \lt 1$ by defining
$$\phi_p(x) = 2f(x) \left[p \mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x) + (1-p)\left(1 - \mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x)\right)\right].$$
(These functions rescale the values of $f$ by $2p$ on the set $\mathcal A$ and by $2(1-p)$ on its complement.)
Every $\phi_p$ is a pdf because (a) its values are non-negative and (b) it integrates to unity:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int \phi_p(x)\,\mathrm dx &= 2p\int_{\mathcal A} f(x)\,\mathrm dx + 2(1-p)\left(1 - \int_{\mathcal A} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right) \\&= 2p\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2(1-p)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\&= 1.\end{aligned}$$
Notice, too, the relationship between each $\phi_p$ and $\phi_{1-p}:$
$$\phi_p(x) + \phi_{1-p}(x) = 2f(x) \left[(p + (1-p)) \mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x) + ((1-p) + 1-(1-p))\left(1 - \mathcal I_{\mathcal A}(x)\right)\right] = 2f(x)$$
for all $x.$  That is, $\phi_p$ and $\phi_{1-p}$ can serve as possible values of $f_1$ and $f_2$ or as possible values of $f_3$ and $f_4.$
Here's the punch line:

When $p\ne q$ (and both values lie between $0$ and $1$), $\phi_p(x)\ne \phi_q(x)$ for all $x.$

Proof.
Recall $f(x)\ne 0$ for any $x.$  When $x\in\mathcal A,$ $\phi_p(x) = 2p f(x) \ne 2q f(x) = \phi_q(x).$  Otherwise, when $x\notin \mathcal A,$ $\phi_p(x) = 2(1-p)f(x)\ne2(1-q)f(x)=\phi_q(x).$  That covers all the possibilities, QED.

In this schematic (but accurate) figure, $\mathcal A$ is the set of $x$ subtended by the gray region.
Counterexample
Let $p$ and $q$ be two numbers between $0$ and $1,$ but (a) neither equals $1/2,$ (b) $p\ne q,$ and (c) $p\ne 1-q.$  Observe that
$$\phi_p + \phi_{1-p} = 2f = \phi_q + \phi_{1-q},$$
yet since $p,1-p,q$ and $1-q$ are all distinct, all four of the $\phi_*$ in this expression never agree on any $x.$

Good analysis (+1), especially demonstrating the process of analyzing the implication of the condition "$f_1(x) \neq \cdots \neq f_4(x)$".

If you are willing to consider the terminology "pdf" or "density" in its advance (i.e., measure theoretic) sense, more trivial counterexamples (compared with @whuber's great answer) can be easily constructed.
By "advance sense", I meant that given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, any non-negative measurable function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
P(A) = \int_A fd\mu, \; A \in \mathscr{F}
\end{align*}
is defined as a density of the probability measure $P$ with respect to another measure $\mu$ (which dominates $P$). For more discussions on this topic, check this Wolfram MathWorld link and our own Cross Validated discussion.
If you accepted this view, let us set $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$, $\mathscr{F} = 2^\Omega$, $\mu$ is the counting measure, and
\begin{align*}
f_i(0) = p_i, f_i(1) = 1 - p_i, \quad i = 1, 2, 3, 4. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
It then follows that
\begin{align*}
& f_1(0) + f_2(0) = p_1 + p_2, f_3(0) + f_4(0) = p_3 + p_4.
\end{align*}
It is clear now that for any distinct $0 < p_1, \ldots, p_4 < 1$ such that
$p_1 + p_2 = p_3 + p_4$, $\eqref{1}$ can serve as a counterexample.  For example, $p_1 = 0.1, p_2 = 0.8, p_3 = 0.3, p_4 = 0.6$.
